# How to get list of all sub directories and files along with their size ordered by size?

Tags: python

How to get list of all sub directories and files along with their size ordered by size in ascending order?

The below code gets me the list of all files, but is not sorted according to size. Please help.

```
import os
import os.path, time
from os.path import join, getsize
count=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Test'):
    for file in list(files):
        fileaddress = os.path.join(root, file)
        print("\nName:",fileaddress)
        print("Time:",time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p",time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(fileaddress))))
        count=count+1
print(count);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize

file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Test'):
    file_list.extend( join(root,f) for f in files )
    #May be *slightly* faster at the expense of a little readability 
    # and a little memory
    # file_list.extend( [ join(root,f) for f in files ] ) 


print (sorted(file_list, key=getsize))
```

And the same thing for `dirs` -- Although I'm not really sure what the "size" of a directory actually is -- You probably can't sort that one with `getsize` (and if you can, you won't get a result that is meaningful).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What if the file_list is huge. Say 200,000+ files. Will calling sorted be efficient? Is there any way to perform the sorted even before invoking the os.walk or while the os.walk is invoked? Or any method with better efficiency? Is this method efficient? Thanks

Comment: @Romaan: The time taken to sort 200,000 results will be nothing compared to the time taken to walk the directories, so there's no efficiency issue here. There may be a _responsiveness_ issue: you won't see anything until the whole process is done, instead of seeing the results show up smoothly over the whole process, but there's no way around that.

Comment: @Romaan -- This is the most efficient way you can do the sorting if you want it to be sorted.  You *need* to know the whole list if you're going to sort (what if the last element is supposed to go first?).

Comment: If you are listing 200,000+ files it's not the sorting that will slow you down, it's the IO overhead of recursing through all those directories and listing all those files.

Comment: @Romaan: For your other question, there is no _direct_ way to get the files in sorted order in the first place. Of course you can `popen` out to `ls` for each directory, or just `find` from the top level, to do the work for you, but there's no guarantee they'll be significantly faster at sorting. Your OS/filesystem probably doesn't have any API to make things faster (POSIX and Windows don't, although BeOS did.) However, you might be able to talk to Spotlight, Windows Desktop Search, etc. instead of the filesystem, if appropriate.

Comment: @mgilson, sorted function is missing in my program. Do I need to import anything to make it work? THANKS

Comment: @mgilson, found the problem, brackets were missing around print statement, as I use the new version of python. Thanks... Working fine for smaller test cases

Comment: @Romaan -- Sorry, I should have guessed you were using python3 by the code you posted.